# Long term probability of a game with multiple outcomes?

Tags: probability, estimation, likelihood, games

I'm not a stats expert so please excuse me if this is a really basic question and I've simply missed the reference...

So let's say this person is playing a game with a small chance of winning, say $P_w$, every time they play. If they lose, they must play again. This game is rather frustrating, so after $m$ plays,  there is also a distinct probability $P_q$ that the player will quit.

What I'm trying to do is determine the probabilities of the player winning or quitting after a large number of rounds $N >> m$.

Probably very basic, but I'm not seeing it somehow...

Comment: You need to specify better the quitting process! Is quitting possible only at round $m$, or at any round after round $m$? With the same quitting probability?

Comment: Sorry, unclear on my part. For the purposes of this model, it's only possible to quit after participating in m rounds, but  alternatively I'd also like to be able to model the (simpler) case that the participant can quit at any time, but this would require a modification of p_q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume the per round win probability is $p_w > 0$. Winning at each round is independent of all other rounds. Then let 
$$
    X_1, X_2, \dots, X_m, \dots, X_n, \dots
$$
be the result of each round, $X_i$ is a bernoulli random variable with distribution $P(X_i=1)=p_w, P(X_i=0)=1-p_w$. Quitting exactly at round $m$ is a bernoulli variable with quitting probability ($Q=1$) equal to $p_q$.
Then the probability of quitting before winning is
$$
   P(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_m=0, Q=1) = (1-p_w)^m \cdot p_q
$$
while the probability of winning before quiting is 
$$
   1-p_q + p_q \cdot (1-(1-p_w)^m)
$$
In the last formula we are assuming that, if not quiting at round $m$, we will play forever so certainly will win, sooner or later.

Comment: Ah, I see it clearly, thanks! I need to modify it sightly however as I should have said that the player has the option of quitting every m rounds, but that's trivial now.